# Property or method "urlImg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: forms, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm trying to create a submit form, but all my v-model are giving me this error.
Here is one example of how I'm creating the form inputs:

```
<template>
<div class="card mx-xl-5">
<!-- Card body -->
<div class="card-body">
  <div>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="pushLocation">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="txtLocationName"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">  <div class="card mx-xl-5">
             <label>Description</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="txtLocDescription"
            placeholder="Description"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type">Tipo de localização</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="type" v-model="typeLoc">
          <option value="museum">Museum</option>
          <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
          <option value="tourist_attraction">Monument</option>
          <option value="art_gallery">Galery</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Imagem</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" v-model="urlImg" placeholder="Link" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is how I'm setting the properties on my script:

```
name: "LocationList",


data: function() {
return {
  id: 0,
  txtLocationName: "",
  txtLocDescription: "",
  typeLoc: "",
  urlImg: "",
  listLocation: [],
  locationChecked: false
};},
methods: {
getLastLocationId() {
  if (this.listLocation.length) {
    return this.listLocation[this.listLocation.length - 1].id;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
},
checkLocationName() {
  if (this.listLocation.length) {
    for (const location of this.listLocation) {
      if (location.Name == this.txtLocName) {
        (this.locationChecked = false),
          alert("nome de localização indisponivel");
      } else {
        this.userChecked = true;
      }
    }
  }
},



pushLocation() {
  this.checkLocationName();
  this.getCoordenates();
  if (this.locationChecked == true) {
    this.$store.commit("ADD_USER", {
      id: this.getLastLocationId() + 1,
      Name: this.txtLocationName,
      Description: this.txtLocDescription,
      Type: this.typeLoc,
      imgLink: this.urlImg
    });
    this.$router.push({ name: "adminLocations" });
  } else {
    alert("erro no registo");
  }
}
```

}

I've done this type of forms multiple times, yet I can figure out why i'm having this error.I added the rest of my vue component. I get the error on all the property and methods, not only on "urlImg".Meaning all the properties that exist in the data and are in the form are giving me this error.

One last point, the final function, pushLocation() is also giving the error, saying that it is not a real function.

Comment: Please post your whole Vue component or a minimal, reproducible example. Since `urlImg` doesn't appear in the template, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: @Tanner I've updated the post. Please have a look

Comment: I apologize for any formatting errors, still getting used to using stack overflow.

Comment: you're missing the right curly bracket `}` for `data: function() {
return {
  id: 0,
  txtLocationName: "",
  txtLocDescription: "",
  typeLoc: "",
  urlImg: "",
  listLocation: [],
  locationChecked: false
};`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm still getting the error though. I believe that curly bracket was missing from me trying to find the problem and messing with the code.

Comment: does `data(){ return {...}}` solve the problem?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim no, it still remains. All the data properties that are mentioned in the form give me that same error. That they are not defined in the instance but referenced during the render.

Comment: Are both sections of code inside the same `.vue` file? You've omitted all the component boilerplate from the question so it's difficult to be sure what you're doing. Check the top-level `<template>` and `<script>` tags are all present and correct (including closing tags) as well as the `export default`. Beyond that, the way to debug this is to try deleting as much of the code as possible to create a minimal test case that exhibits the error. Once you've got it down to a handful of lines it should be obvious what the problem is, or if it isn't you'll have something nice and short to post here.

Comment: is that happen on page is mounted or when user click on submit button? your code should be work fine, check your spelling typography, semicolon, trailing comma and brackets sometime it can affect this error